# Mysql procedure which need to return result in one table

Tags: mysql

I want following Procedure Output in one table. Actually it displaying output in multiple table when I am running it into HeidlSql.

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure daily_report()
BEGIN
select count(Transaction1) from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select count(Transaction1) from test1 where RESPONSE='Y' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select (sum(RESPONSE='Y')/count(Transaction1))*100 from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select count(Transaction1) from test1 where RESPONSE='N' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select (sum(RESPONSE='N')/count(Transaction1))*100 from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select count(Transaction1),DATE1 from test1 where RESPONSE='N' and ERROR1='30' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select (sum(RESPONSE='N' AND ERROR1='30')/count(Transaction1))*100 from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select count(Transaction1) from test1 where RESPONSE='N' and ERROR1 not like '30' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
select (sum(RESPONSE='N' AND ERROR1 not like '30')/count(Transaction1))*100 from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
end
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a single resultset, you have combine your queries with [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).
One caveat is that they all must return the same number of columns.

```
SELECT 'metric1' AS name, count(Transaction1) AS value1, NULL AS value2 from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1)
UNION
SELECT 'metric2', count(Transaction1), NULL from test1 where RESPONSE='Y' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1)
UNION
select 'metric3', (sum(RESPONSE='Y')/count(Transaction1))*100, NULL from test1 where (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1)
UNION
select 'metric4', count(Transaction1),DATE1 from test1 where RESPONSE='N' and ERROR1='30' and (DATE1 between curdate() and curdate()+1);
```